# How to rotate one plot out of many when using knitr?

Tags: r, knitr

I am using knitr with plots. I would like to rotate one of them 90 degree. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}


<<cache=TRUE, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, comment=NA, eval=TRUE, results=asis>>=

library("ggplot2")
library("gridExtra")

func <- function(data,x,y) {

  p1 <- ggplot(data.frame(data), aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point()
  p2 <- ggplot(data.frame(data), aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point()
  p3 <- ggplot(data.frame(data), aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point()
  p4 <- ggplot(data.frame(data), aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point()

  grid.newpage() 
    pushViewport(viewport(width = .9, height = .9,layout = grid.layout(nrow=2, ncol=2)))
    print(p1,vp = viewport(layout.pos.row = 1, layout.pos.col = 1))
    print(p2,vp = viewport(layout.pos.row = 2, layout.pos.col = 1))
    print(p3,vp = viewport(layout.pos.row = 1, layout.pos.col = 2))
    print(p4,vp = viewport(layout.pos.row = 2, layout.pos.col = 2))

  grid.newpage() 
    pushViewport(viewport(width = .8, height = .5,layout = grid.layout(nrow=1, ncol=2)))
    print(p1,vp = viewport(layout.pos.row = 1, layout.pos.col = 1))
    print(p2,vp = viewport(layout.pos.row = 1, layout.pos.col = 2))

}

x <- runif(20,0,1)
y <- rnorm(20)
test <- cbind(x,y)
func(test,x=test$x,y=test$y)

@    

\end{document}
```

I would like to rotate both the second page and the graph 90 degree. I know I can use this for one page:

```
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\begin{landscape}
....
\end{landscape}
```

But the two plots are arranged by grid.newpage() within one function. How can I achieve that? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Note you are expected to write `results='asis'` instead of `asis`. As the answer below shows, this (rotation by 90 degrees) is the example used in the documentation.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think you can use `out.extra` in the chunk options:

From knitr docs: http://yihui.name/knitr/options

> out.extra: (NULL; character) extra options for figures, e.g.
>   out.extra='angle=90' in LaTeX output will rotate the figure by 90
>   degrees; it can be an arbitrary string, e.g. you can write multiple
>   figure options in this option; it also applies to HTML images (extra
>   options will be written into the  tag, e.g.
>   out.extra='style="display:block;"')

```
<<out.extra='angle=90', cache=TRUE, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, comment=NA, eval=TRUE, results='asis'>>=
# ... 
@
```

Comment: Thanks. Can it be like `out.extra='angle=c(0,90)'` because I have two plots and I only want to rotate the second one.

Comment: The two plots should be in seperate chunks if you want to declare different options for them.

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen I think it is possible with CSS3, e.g. `out.extra="style='transform:rotate(90deg);'"`, but that relies on the browser support (see, e.g. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp)

Comment: @Lin That is a reasonable request; please write it to https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues so I'll try to implement it in the future.

Comment: @Lin It has been implemented now: https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/430#issuecomment-10926825