# How to plot a decision tree horizontally in R Markdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown, rpart, mlr

In R Markdown, I would like to plot a decision tree horizontally, so that it fits better the entire PDF page. This code plots it vertically:

````
```{r, message=FALSE, warning = FALSE, echo=FALSE, cache = FALSE}

rpart.lrn <- makeLearner("classif.rpart", predict.type = "prob", fix.factors.prediction = FALSE) 
model = train(rpart.lrn, task = classif.task, subset = train.set)
tree <- getLearnerModel(model)
rpart.plot(tree) # visualise the tree
```
````

How can I plot it **horizontally** instead?

Comment: `ggplot2` has that option, I don't have a tree model to test this on but trying to create a ggplot object from your plot and adding the `coord_flip` function to it might work. and example can be seen [here](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-rotate-a-graph-reverse-and-flip-the-plot)

Comment: Have you tried so set fig.height and fig.width, for example `{r ggpair, echo=FALSE, message = FALSE, warning = FALSE, fig.height = 12, fig.width = 12}`

Comment: You can rotate the plot like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13593949/how-to-rotate-one-plot-out-of-many-when-using-knitr but using rpart.plot I don't see a chance.

Comment: @PhilippPro this worked. Pleas add this comment as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried so set fig.height and fig.width, for example `{r ggpair, echo=FALSE, message = FALSE, warning = FALSE, fig.height = 12, fig.width = 12}`